# Liquibase 'addCheckConstraint' for ENUM colum in Oracle DB allows any character

Tags: oracle, yaml, liquibase

I have a ENUM column and I am using liquibase `addCheckConstraint` to allow only ENUM values. However, `addCheckConstraint` doesnt work and allows any value. My yaml changelog looks as follows:

```xml
    - changeSet:
        id: 1565352995028-1
        author: Zafrullah Syed
        changes:
        - createTable:
            columns:
            - column:
                constraints:
                  primaryKey: true
                name: ID
                type: NUMBER(19, 0)
            - column:
                name: STATUS_ENUM
                type: VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)
            tableName: BOOKING
        - addCheckConstraint:
            constraintBody: STATUS_ENUM IN ('ERROR', 'CONFIRMED', 'QUEUED', 'REJECTED')
            constraintName: enumcheck
            tableName: SOME_TABLE
```

I am Using Oracle db.

If I try to run a sql query, then constraint works well:

```sql
ALTER TABLE SOME_TABLE 
ADD CONSTRAINT enumcheck CHECK (status_enum IN ('ERROR', 'CONFIRMED', 'QUEUED', 'REJECTED'));
```

I tried to add another `enableCheckConstraint` to enable the existing check constraint but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Try using the `updateSQL` command to see what SQL Liquibase is generating and compare that to the SQL you generated yourself.

Answer (score 2):

`addCheckConstraint` is accessible only for the [pro](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/add_check_constraint.html) version, do you have it?